# MongoCollection How to get grand children?

Tags: mongodb

The below query works fine and fetches departments and associations.

```
MongoCollection.findOne("{name: '"+name+"'}, children: ['departments', 
'associations']").as(Employee.class);
```

I have sub-children for each department - items which i would like to retrieve along with the same.

Not sure how to retrieve with the above query..

Tried the below but it doesn't work...

```
MongoCollection.findOne("{name: '"+name+"'}, children: ['departments', 
'associations', 'departments.items']").as(Employee.class);
```

1. How to retrieve the grand children automatically?
2. How to retrieve the grand json elements?

Thanks in advance.

Example Document for reference.

Users.json

```
{  
"_id":ObjectId("577a3f7b4309be18d8c40121"),
"name":"admin",
"email":"admin.guna@gmail.com",
"firstName":"guna",
"lastName":"g",
"password":"bevgI3awgpagF2o6ekUObEQ14UmdskWpG",
"roles":[  
  {  
     "name":"sales",
     "description":"sales",
     "_id":ObjectId("577a3f7b4309be18d8c40122")
  }
]
}
```

Roles.json

```
{  
"_id":ObjectId("577a3f7b4309be18d8c40122"),
"name":"sales",
"description":"sales",
"permission":[  
  {  
     "name":"SalesView",
     "description":"SalesView",
     "_id":ObjectId("577a3f7c4309be18d8c40123")
  }
]
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `string` as argument for your query, you can directly use `object`.

Comment: could you post example document?

Comment: i have posted the example document. could you please both help with your suggestions and solutions?

Comment: i don't understand Blaze. could you please let me know how to use object directly with a sample code snippet for the above?